# I want to open onclick two pages one internal and one external

Tags: javascript, html

can you tell me how to fix it on this code exactly? here I have two internal codes and two external (to youtube)

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>LS_model</title>
<link href="ls.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="space"><br></div>
<div id="container">
<div id="wb_Image1" style="position:absolute;left:62px;top:291px;width:876px;height:524px;z-index:0;">
<img src="images/Background.png" id="Image1" alt=""></div>
<div id="wb_Image2" style="position:absolute;left:75px;top:31px;width:840px;height:260px;z-index:1;">
<img src="images/ads.gif" id="Image2" alt=""></div>
<div id="wb_Image3" style="position:absolute;left:126px;top:343px;width:140px;height:57px;z-index:2;">
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='./page22.html';window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5u7ytZmxstY');return false;"><img src="images/videoss-b.gif" id="Image3" alt=""></a></div>
<div id="wb_Image4" style="position:absolute;left:723px;top:344px;width:140px;height:56px;z-index:3;">
<a href="#" onclick="window.location.href='./page1.html';window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5u7ytZmxstY');return false;"><img src="images/Photos-b.gif" id="Image4" alt=""></a></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what issue you are facing??

Comment: the problem is when I click it supposed to go to next page and open link of youtube on new tab but here it just open youtube on same tab...

Comment: I don't see any issue in your code. It is working fine for me.

Comment: I just discover the problem (return false) change to (return true) thank you anyway :)

Comment: also check out target='_blank' http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Use `window.open` to open two pages and remove **return false** from your code.

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('./page1.html');window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5u7ytZmxstY');"><img src="images/Photos-b.gif" id="Image4" alt=""></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

For opening in a new tab, use:

```
window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5u7ytZmxstY', '_blank');
```

And for opening internal, use:

```
window.open('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5u7ytZmxstY');
```